# How to use RabbitMQ list of hosts connection parameter

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to use the `IList<string>` parameter when creating a connection in the C# rabbitMQ library:

[IConnection CreateConnection(IList hostnames)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Collections.Generic.IList%7BSystem.String%7D))

My code is as follows:

```
    private IConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            UserName = _userName,
            Password = _password,
            VirtualHost = _vhost,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = DEFAULT_AUTO_RECOVER,
            RequestedHeartbeat = HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
            Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
        };
        // _hosts contains valid IPs "###.###.###.###"
        return connectionFactory.CreateConnection(_hosts);
    }
```

But regardless of what I suppose for the `hosts` parameter it doesn't seem to connect (I get "None of the specified endpoints were reachable")

Even if my list contains only one element.

Now, if I use the **single** host implementation like this, it works correctly:

```
    private IConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            UserName = _userName,
            Password = _password,
            VirtualHost = _vhost,
            AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = DEFAULT_AUTO_RECOVER,
            RequestedHeartbeat = HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
            Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
            HostName = _hosts.First() // or just one string
        };
        return connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
    }
```

I recognize that RabbitMQ suggests not storing the set of hosts on the client but I'm just trying to get their provided method to work.

Comment: Strange, because according to the latest [source](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/e8f0a3aca3ab16ca3f2537dbc78543c91ff58f92/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs#L349) `connectionFactory.CreateConnection();` calls `CreateConnection(new List<string>() { HostName }, null);`

Comment: Yes. If I send a list of one item it works. perhaps my testing methodology is incorrect. I understood this method to keep trying to find a node through all members of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to set a value for the `HostnameSelector` property of the connection factory

```
private IConnection CreateConnection()
{
    var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        UserName = _userName,
        Password = _password,
        VirtualHost = _vhost,
        AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = DEFAULT_AUTO_RECOVER,
        RequestedHeartbeat = HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS,
        Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
        HostnameSelector = new RandomHostnameSelector()
    };
    // _hosts contains valid IPs "###.###.###.###"
    return connectionFactory.CreateConnection(_hosts);
}
```

RabbitMQ provides a RandomHostnameSelector

```
class RandomHostnameSelector : IHostnameSelector
{
    string IHostnameSelector.NextFrom(IList<string> options)
    {
        return options.RandomItem();
    }
}
```

Or you could create your own implementation of `IHostnameSelector` to have your own host selection strategy.

Comment: I don't have this implementation in the latest version of the RabbitMQ .NET library?

Comment: @Matthew what version of the RabbitMQ client library are you using? See [docs for v3.6.0](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.0-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html)

Comment: @Matthew The documentation for ConnectionFactory does say that the HostnameSelector is only used when recovering a connection. Are you sure that your host names are valid in the `IList<string> hostnames`?

Comment: In my test one of the hosts I'm passing is unreachable. My expectation is that the connection and recovery will move on to another host. For example I may know multiple nodes in the cluster. If node1 is unreachable I would expect it to try node2.

Comment: Also I'm using 3.6.1. The class you pointed out is not exposed, it's internal. Not a problem though, I can create my own. It doesn't resolve my issue :(

Comment: I spoke too soon. I upgraded to 3.6.1 and it works now. I did have to implement a `IHostnameSelector` though.

Comment: Starting with v4.0, `IHostnameSelector` has been replaced by `IEndpointResolver` . See https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/195