# Connecting to multiple RabbitMQ hosts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have a .NET Core application and am trying to connect to multiple RabbitMQ hosts.  Below is my sample code but when I run I get a `BrokerUnreachableException`.

```
var hosts = rabbitConnectionString.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();

var connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection(hosts);
```

Where my `rabbitConnectionString` looks like 
`amqp://user:password@server:5672/FileHandler,amqp://user:password@server:5662/FileHandler`

Is it possible to connect to multiple hosts?

Update:  Below is my updated code.  I am still getting an error for host not reachable

```
var hosts = "dev.mydomain.com" //I have also tried "ampq://dev.mydomain.com

var connection = new ConnectionFactory()
{
  Port = 5662,
  UserName = "FileHandler",
  Password = "FileHandler",
  AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
  NetworkRecoveryInterval = new TimeSpan(2000),
  VirtualHost = "FileHandler"
}
.CreateConnection(hosts);
```

Does the list of hosts require an IP Address

Comment: There should be no issue opening multiple connections but you would need to create a separate connection to each host.

Answer (score 0):

You can give multiple hosts as input to your Connection Factory. The RabbitMQ client retries with the given hosts until a connection is made.

```
# List of hosts
var hosts = Array(new Address("IP address 1"), new Address("IP address 2"))

# Connection factort object.
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()

# Setting connection factory arguments.
factory.setPort(5672)
factory.setUsername("")
factory.setPassword("")
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)
factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(2000)

# Passing the list of hosts to get the connection.
var connection = factory.CreateConnection(hosts)
```

Reference:

1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#connecting
2. [How to use RabbitMQ list of hosts connection parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849789/how-to-use-rabbitmq-list-of-hosts-connection-parameter/36852029)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still struggling with this and have provided updated code above.